# Using $ref in Vue and JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, vuejs2

I'm using Vue and JQuery on a project I work. I know that it is not the best match, but I don't have any other choice (No Vue library which does what I need). Anyway, I'm trying to create an organization chart which has a click node event listener. I created the following method:

```
clickNode: function($node, data) {
    $node.on('click', function() {
        this.node = data;
        $(".showsubtree").show();
    });
}
```

It should open a modal when the node is being clicked. When I click the node, it just prints to the console the following message:

```
jQuery.fn.init [prevObject: jQuery.fn.init(1)]
```

If the library was written in Vue, the method should have been something like this:

```
clickNode: function(node, data) {
    node.addEventListener('click',() => {
        this.node = data;
        this.$refs.showsubtree.show();
    })
},
```

In the template section, I use:

```
<showsubtree ref="showsubtree" :ps-data="node" :closed="closeModal"></showsubtree>
```

Please note that I changed the `ref` to `class` in the first piece of code so the `$.(".showsubtree")` would work. I think that the problem is hidden in the use of `$ref` because with that it would work, but when I switch to a JQuery library, it does not work. If `$ref` is really the key to solve this issue, which keyword should I use in JQuery in order to replace `$ref`? If not, what could help solve this issue? The main goal is to pop-up a modal when a specific node is clicked on the tree.